# How can I avoid creating redundant instantiations of a similar object here?

Tags: java

I have to write a code that keeps record of competitors participating to different events.
Competitor is a class with the following attributes: name, surname, age, id.
Event is a class with the following attributes: name, date, a list of competitors.

Professor then says that I must also keep track of whether a competitor has confirmed their participation to the event or not. That is a competitor could be listed in an event but may not have confirmed their participation to it yet. How to implement this is up to me.

So, keeping in mind that a competitor may participate to multiple events, I would like to avoid creating a Competitor object for one same person for each event he's taking part in.

I was thinking of something that sounds optimal in C but that I can't translate into Java: I would like to create a new class, CompetitorInEvent, that would hold all the information contained in Competitor plus the boolean representing the confirmation to the event (which event is not stated, because the list such competitorInEvent belongs to already tells it).

And as a consequence I would turn the list of competitors into a list of competitors-in-event.

CompetitorInEvent shouldn't extend Competitor, but rather hold a reference to a Competitor object. In C, I would promise to only access this reference for reading and never for writing and I would have the struct CompetitorInEvent storing only an address and a boolean (or rather a short in C). This seems correct to me because I'm not instancing same real world objects multiple times or wasting memory. But is there a way to achieve these same goals in Java? I'm aware that pointers are not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java holds references to objects, which you can think of as pointers. You just cannot do any arithmetic on references like you can to pointers in C. So this code shows two CompetitorInEvents referencing the same Competitor:

```
class CompetitorInEvent {
    private Competitor competitor;

    public CompetitorInEvent(Competitor competitor) {
        this.competitor = competitor;
    }
}
```

Then to use this:

```
Competitor aCompetitor = new Competitor();
CompetitorInEvent event1 = new CompetitorInEvent(aCompetitor);
CompetitorInEvent event2 = new CompetitorInEvent(aCompetitor);
```

Now there is only one Competitor instantiated, with 3 references to it: The local variable aCompetitor and the two events. Note that Java maintains reference counts to the object, and will not garbage-collect (destroy) aCompetitor until the local variable goes out of scope (or is reassigned to another reference), and the two CompetitorInEvent objects are both destroyed/garbage-collected.